# Why cin behaves differently if previous input is same as current input?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class node{
int data;
node *prev;
node *next;
public:
    node(int n){
        data=n;
        prev=NULL;
        next=NULL;      
    }
    void insert_end(node**,node**);
    void insert_beg(node**,node**);
    void insert_after(node**,node**);
    void delete_end(node**,node**);
    void delete_start(node**,node**);
    void display(node**,node**);
    node* find(node**,node**,int n);
};

void node::insert_end(node **start,node **end){
    int n;
    if(*start!=NULL){
        cout<<"Enter number \n";
        cin>>n;
        node *obj=new node(n);
        (*end)->next=obj;
        obj->prev=*end;
        *end=(*end)->next;
    }
    else{
        cout<<"Enter number \n";
        cin>>n;
        node *obj=new node(n);
        *start=obj;
        *end=obj;
    } 
}

void node::insert_beg(node **start,node **end){
    int n;
    if(*start!=NULL){
        cout<<"Enter number \n";
        cin>>n;
        node *obj=new node(n);
        (*start)->prev=obj;
        obj->next=*start;
        *start=obj;
    }
    else{
        cout<<"Enter number \n";
        cin>>n;
        node *obj=new node(n);
        *start=obj;
        *end=obj;
    } 
}

void node::insert_after(node **start,node **end){
    int n,nn;
    if(*start!=NULL){
        cout<<"Enter number \n";
        cin>>n;
        cout<<"Enter number after which element is to be inserted\n";
        cin>>nn;
        node *pos=find(start,end,nn);
        if(pos==NULL){
            cout<<"No such element "<<nn<<endl;
        }
        else{
            node *obj=new node(n);
            obj->prev=pos;
            obj->next=pos->next;
            pos->next->prev=obj;
            pos->next=obj;
        }
    }
    else{
        cout<<"Enter number \n";
        cin>>n;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(10000,'\n');
        node *obj=new node(n);
        *start=obj;
        *end=obj;
    } 
}

void node::display(node** start,node** end){
    if(*start==NULL)cout<<"Empty list\n";
    else{
        node *temp=*start;
        cout<<"List is :"<<endl;
        while(temp!=NULL){          
            cout<<"\n"<<(temp)->data;
            temp=(temp)->next;
        }
    }
}

void node::delete_end(node** start,node** end){
    if(*start==NULL)cout<<"Empty list";
    else{
        node *temp=*end;
        temp->prev->next=temp->next;
        *end=(*end)->prev;
    }
}

void node::delete_start(node** start,node** end){
    if(*start==NULL)cout<<"Empty list";
    else{
        node *temp=*start;
        temp->next->prev=NULL;
        *start=(*start)->next;
    }
}

node* node::find(node** start,node** end,int n){
    node *temp=*start;
    if(temp==NULL)return NULL;
    else{
        while(temp!=NULL){
            if(temp->data==n)return temp;
            else temp=temp->next;
        }
        return NULL;
    }
}

int main(){
node *start=NULL,*end=NULL;
int choice,flag=0;
while(1){
    cout<<"\n1.Exit\n2.Insert at end\n3.Insert at front\n4.Insert after\n5.Insert before\n6.Display\n7.Delete last\n8.Delete first\nMake Choice : ";
    cin>>choice;
    switch(choice){
        case 1: flag=1;
            break;
        case 2: start->insert_end(&start,&end);
            break;
        case 3: start->insert_beg(&start,&end);
            break;
        case 4: start->insert_after(&start,&end);
            break;
        case 6: start->display(&start,&end);
            break;
        case 7: start->delete_end(&start,&end);
            break;
        case 8: start->delete_start(&start,&end);
            break;
        default:cout<<"Wrong input\n";
    }
    if(flag==1)break;
}
}
```

I get a segmentation fault(core dumped) when I call insert_after() and give the the element after which new element is to be entered same as any element of the linked list[image: sample output when input same as a element in linked list! [sample output when input is different from any previous linked list element]

Comment: Things get much easier if you separate input and output from list manipulation. (This looks like a program written using free functions and later transformed into a "you must use classes to pass the course"-style C++ program.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A big problem is that you are calling a function on `start`, which is `NULL`, causing undefined behavior.

Instantiate `start` before calling anything on it.

E.g. this is bad:

```
node *start=NULL,*end=NULL;
// ...
case 4: start->insert_after(&start,&end);
```

You probably need to rethink your design.

So, I would recommend you instead implement your behavior with a `std::vector`.

Comment: @Barry: It seems your comment happened at the same time as my last edit, so I'm not sure what exactly you're referring to. Probably the case where start and end were pointed at each other, in which case, I would argue that `n` wasn't really added twice at all, but once, creating a circular linked list, which would break OP's `find` function, so I removed that portion of my answer.

Comment: "start doesn't point at end or vice versa" <== `start` and `end` both point to `obj`. That's the correct behavior.

Comment: @Barry: Apologies, I was not clear. Correct behavior or not, the question I was trying to ask OP was whether or not they wanted to be able to get to start via `end->prev` or get to end via `start->next`. I agree that a linked list of one element should have `start == end`, so I'll remove that question to OP.

Comment: Thanks. I instead implemented the code again separating the methods from node class and creating a new class with the start and end pointers and the manipulation methods as a part of this new class and made this class friend class of node class. This works well

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the success case of `insert_after`:

```
node *obj = new node(n);
obj->prev = pos;
obj->next = pos->next;
pos->next->prev = obj; // <==
pos->next = obj;
```

What if we have a list of one `node`, which is the `node` we were looking for, so `pos` points to it. In that case, `pos->next` is `NULL`, so the assignment to `pos->next->prev` would involve dereferencing `NULL`, which is likely the cause of your segfault.

That part should be:

```
if (pos->next) {
    pos->next->prev = obj;
}
else {
    // no next? must be at the end
    *end = obj;
}
```

That said, all of your `node` methods should be free functions, not class methods. Your call to `insert_after` should really look like:

```
case 4:
    insert_after(&start,&end);
    break;
```

As is, since you're starting with `start` as `NULL`, all of the calls are undefined behavior - but you don't need them as methods anyway since you're only ever accessing data through the `start` or `end` pointers.

Lastly, why is this here?

```
cin.clear();
cin.ignore(10000,'\n');
```

I'm pretty sure you don't need that in this program.

Comment: +1 for being much more clear than I was about the issue of `next` and `prev` not getting you where you want to go

Comment: Hey Barry thanks for pointing out the bug in insert_after method. What I don't get is your suggestion of using free functions instead of class methods. Can you throw some light on that?